# Как задать ширину контента для текста в input

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: Скриншот]

Как показано на скриншоте существен ширина формы для текста, как её задать не знаю.
Побывал обычные padding'и, задеться ширина для input но не для ширины текста в нём.

HTML код контента в блоке в котором находиться input

```css
.page-subscribe input {
  border: solid 2px #4265B7;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 35px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-subscribe">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="page-subscribe-content">
      <h2><span>Subscribe</span>Signup For A Trail</h2>
      <p>Create your free account now & get 30 days free <br> trail No credit card required</p>
      <!-- Нужный элемент -->
      <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address">
      <!-- Нужный элемент -->
      <button class="btn-primary" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
    </div>
    <div class="page-subscribe-img">
      <img src="img/Robot.png" alt="Robot">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Скиньте стиль для блока, в котором лежит input и кнопка. Желательно весь css. Либо попробуйте для input "padding-right: npx", где n - длина кнопки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Определите ширину кнопки **Subscribe**, сделайте фиксированный размер в CSS для этой кнопки, а уже инпуту выставите `padding-right: *ширина кнопки + желаемый отступ от неё*px;`

Вот пример:

```css
.block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 220px;
  position: relative;
}

.block input[type="text"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 85px; /* ширина кноки + желаемый отступ */
  text-overflow: '..'; /* необязательно */
  border: 2px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.block input[type="button"] {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75px; /* ширина кнопки фиксирована */
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  border: 2px solid darkgreen;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <input type="text" value="bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla-bla">
  <input type="button" value="subscribe">
</div>
```

Comment: Да, это решение по лучше моего.

Answer (score 0):

> Не заморачивайся.
>
> укажи фиксированную ширину! `Width: 150px;`
>
> а остальное добей отступом `padding`

```
width:150px;
padding-right:20px;
```

или еще способ.

```
<div class="m1">
   <input type="email"/>
</div>
```

css:

```
.m1{
width:100%;
}
.m1 > input{
width:90%;
padding-right:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ввел для imput ограничение на ввод до 35 символов и мне этого хватило.

```
<div class="page-subscribe">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="page-subscribe-content">
            <h2><span>Subscribe</span>Signup For A Trail</h2>
            <p>Create your free account now & get 30 days free <br> trail No credit card required</p>
            <!-- Нужный элемент -->
            <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" maxlength="35">
            <!-- Нужный элемент -->
            <button class="btn-primary" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
        </div>
        <div class="page-subscribe-img">
        <img src="img/Robot.png" alt="Robot">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```